# Como padronizar a formatação dos códigos javascript e php?

Tags: javascript, php

Tenho um tempo já nas linguagens, mas sempre que me deparo com códigos de outros ou estou em um trabalho diferente, cada um tem uma forma de padronizar diferente.

Existe algum padrão reconhecido, tipo W3C, ou alguma ferramenta que valide o código?

Answer (score 1):

Tem sim. Existem vários padrões, inclusive ferramentas online que "embelezam" seu código de acordo com algum padrão existente.

http://beta.phpformatter.com

http://jsbeautifier.org

Tem também o PHP_CodeSniffer, pacote integrante do Pear, que você pode embutir na sua IDE favorita.

No meu caso, uso ele para validar o código PHP de colaboradores antes de aceitar um pull request nas ferramentas de versionamento. Sempre que um arquivo PHP é salvo, minha IDE (komodo edit) automaticamente chama o comando:

```
/usr/lib/php/pear/phpcs %F --standard=phpcs
```

Exemplo de parte de um resultado sem validação:

---

FILE: phpexample.php

### FOUND 908 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 238 LINE(S)

102 | ERROR   | The variable names for parameters $get (3) and $main (4) do
      |         | not align

102 | ERROR   | The comments for parameters $get (3) and $main (4) do not
      |         | align

199 | ERROR   | Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed

199 | ERROR   | Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 4 spaces, found
      |         | 1

---

E você escolhe entre vários formatos.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O **PHP** definiu alguns padrões neste [arquivo](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS;hb=HEAD).

Sobre **Javascript** você pode encontrar nestes lugares:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_Tips
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style#JavaScript_practices
- https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Também é importante verificar se a empresa ou projeto que você trabalha segue algum padrão ou se tem algum formatador de código.

Abs!

Comment: valeu. Olhei esse e os outros, mas parece que ninguém gosta de tabs, exceto nós brasileiros

Answer (score 0):

Para php existem algumas recomendaçõe propostas que são:

[PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), Regula a definção de namespaces, para que a forma de carregar(autoload) classes seja um padrão independete do framework/lib utilizada, pois hoje alguns frameworks utlizam mecanismos proprios, quer dizer se precisar somente um componente é quase obrigado a a utilizar o framework inteiro por causa das dependecias ou do autoload proprio.

[PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md), Qugere uma padronização, de qual tipo de código alguns arquivos devem ter e um um pouco de codestand.

[PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), Sugere basicamente codestand

Existem algumas ferramente como o [codesniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) que serve para mostrar deficiencias no código por exemplo código duplicado ou tabulação errada, isso é feita de através de regras definidas pelo usuario, aqui tem um [artigo](http://www.joomlaavancado.eti.br/site/index.php/tutoriais/13-joomla/82-disciplinando-a-codificacao-com-o-codesniffer) para maiores informações.